# Relativistic acceleration of a rocket?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm trying to solve a physics brain-teaser and getting nowhere fast. My knowledge of special relativity is very basic.

In the problem a rocket is flying linearly at relativistic speeds (say $v>0.9c$), in the absence of external force fields. The rocket loses mass $m$ which is converted to mechanical work $W$ done on the rocket, acc:

$$dW=-\alpha dm$$

Where $\alpha$ is an efficiency coefficient ($\mathrm{Jkg^{-1}}$).

In the absence external force fields all mechanical work is converted to kinetic energy, so:

$$dW=dK$$

Relativistic kinetic energy is given by:

$$K=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}-mc^2$$

I tried to set up a differential equation as follows:

$$-\alpha dm=\frac{(m+dm)c^2}{\sqrt{1-(v+dv)^2/c^2}}-(m+dm)c^2-\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}+mc^2$$

Even with some reworking and elimination of higher order infinitesimals that's very unyielding and I'm not sure its even correct. In fact it doesn't take the $K$ of the mass $dm$ into account. Probably conservation of momentum is also needed to be take into consideration.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to note that the acceleration $a'$ in the inertial frame of the spectators is related to the proper acceleration in the rest frame of the rocket, $a$, by:

$$ a' = \frac{a}{\gamma^3} $$

So just work out the acceleration felt by the observers on the rocket in their rest frame, which is regular Newtonian mechanics, then feed the expression for $a$ into the equation above and solve the (probably exceedingly messy) resulting equation of motion.

Comment: Ok, that sounds easy-peasy [cough!]. Thanks.

Comment: There is a nice succinct review of relativistic acceleration in the web page below .  Beware spoilers though; it does give some useful answers that you might want to derive yourself . . .   http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/special-relativity/lecture-6/relativistic-kinematics/

Comment: possibly of interest https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36112/12102